# How to load relations with tree entity with typeorm?

Tags: typeorm

I have a Role Entity and a Route Entity which is tree structure, and they're ManyToMany relation.

Now I want to retrive all the roles via RoleRepository.find({relations: ['routes']}), which will load all the roles data as expected, however the routes prop won't automaticlly load it's children data, which looks like:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: 'route1',
  routes: [{
    id: 1,
    path: '/home'
  }]
}]
```

I've checked all documentation and had no clue to make it.

```
@Entity()
export class Role {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id: number

  ... some other columns

  @ManyToMany(type => Route, route => route.roles)
  public routes: Route[]
}
```

```
@Entity()
@Tree('materialized-path')
export class Route {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id: number

  @TreeParent()
  public parent: Route

  @TreeChildren({ cascade: true })
  public children: Route[]

  @ManyToMany(type => Role, role => role.routes)
  @JoinTable()
  public roles: Role[]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way to get the relations when is a tree entity is making:

```
await getManager().getTreeRepository(Route).findTrees({ relations: ["roles"] });
```

Answer (score 0):

To load the children of a relation you can just add the property you want within the relations array like this:

```
RoleRepository.find({relations: ['routes', 'routes.roles']})
```

it should give you something like that:

```
"route": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "route1",
        "roles": [{
                "id": 1,
                "name": "role1",
                "routes": [{
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "route1"
                    }, {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "route2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. The repository is a tree repository, your solution only joins on the first level. All other child-Routes would not be joined. But how do you get the roles of every child-Route as well?